# Programatically add product to basket - Error: The product could not be found

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, shopping-cart

Hi guys I have a small code snippet and am trying to add a product to basket in Magento via PHP.

Whatever I try (I've searched for a lot of snippets) I just get "The product could not be found." error. I have dialled my code back to a very short and simple snippet to try and get this working.

Can anyone spot what might be causing this?

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $sku="prodsku";
    $qty=1;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    var_dump($product);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I am using a var_dump on the product to make sure it is finding it and if I remove the line:

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
```

It then dumps the product information and it all looks fine.

SOLVED: This single product was not physically ADDED to the website under Product > Websites, I also have to change to load by ID rather than SKU as it was throwing up stock errors.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to add product to cart

```
   try
{

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();

    $qty=1;

    $productId='10'; //product id

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

    if($product->getSku()!='')
    {
        $paramater = array(
            'product' => $productId,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'form_key' => $formKey
        );

        $cart->addProduct($product, $paramater);
        $cart->save();
    }
    else
    {
        Mage::log('product not vailable');  
    }
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}catch (Exception $e)
{
     Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Same error as before.

Comment: i edit my answer you check

Comment: No error but doesn't add to cart either

Comment: any log print in log file??

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow Code:

```
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  
// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();
$productid=1;
$qty=1;
// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => $qty,
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $request);

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: check if the product is_in_stock?

Comment: ["is_in_stock"]=> NULL - I have manage stock set to no

Comment: what is quantity?

Comment: It's probably not set to the Website, for anyone digging for an answer to this years later...